# How to remove deleted post from "Following" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, follow-posts

Few weeks ago I started following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811542/need-to-move-tab-focus-to-the-popup-element), which was deleted by OP later. Now I want to remove this post from the "Following" tab, but an attempt to unfollow it causes an error.

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

I'm quite confused by this error message, because I'm not voting on this question. I also wasn't notified about its deletion. What is the proper way to unfollow the deleted question?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the "following" feature has been implemented as a vote-type. Distinct from up, down, close, reopen, delete, etc. Which gives rise to this sort of bug, I suppose.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question (status-review for 2 months)

Comment: @Scratte Thank you, it seems so. It makes sense to automatically unfollow question where it's deleted, since voting is blocked on deleted posts

Comment: [Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192) created a comprehensive [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zU-o6cr9DeLKB3na9aEld13Ixf30f4qpGWPidILtmPs/view) for what's covered by the following feature. Question being deleted is not covered as can be seen at "Post was deleted". And there is noway to unfollow a deleted post.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I disagree that automatically unfollowing deleted posts is appropriate. What if the post is undeleted? Isn't that something some people who are following a post would want to be notified about?

Comment: @Makyen Then it should be an ability to unfollow it any time. I totally agree with this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question#comment1160137_346423)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski FYI, as stated recently in the main meta's [Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/562482), plus that I confirmed myself & then updated my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349292/562482) which is similar to your question, this now works for most deleted posts (although apparently not for ones with certain special status, e.g., being locked as mentioned in that Meta question).

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Can you please mark the [corresponding Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post) as completed as well, and post an answer explaining the cause of the bug?

Comment: @gparyani The answer re: the cause of the bug is here (on yet another duplicate post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/349251