# Can't unfollow deleted answer

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, follow-posts

Pretty sure this issue is different from [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398215/how-to-remove-deleted-post-from-following-tab), as I don't get a popup. (Though with the new UI, who knows?)

Recently, I followed a couple of answers that later got deleted. Since I don't have the rep for it, I can't unfollow from the answer directly. If it helps, these are the answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254607/no-exception-or-error-is-detected-still-not-executing-the-stored-procedure-as-a/70254867#70254867
- [Error on line 1, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Unexpected character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910520/error-on-line-1-column-1-of-pubspec-lock-unexpected-character/70223488#70223488)

Other information:

- When I try to unfollow from the Following tab, it shows "Follow" again, but when I refresh the page, the post is still listed.
- There is also no indication that the answers were deleted looking at the view itself. By contrast, unfollowing deleted questions still works, and these will show up as red in Following.

Comment: No repro, clicking unfollow on a deleted answer in the following tab does indeed unfollow it. FF 96.0b3 (64-bit)

Comment: Scratch that, I got confused once again because of Stack Overflows _garbage_ design. Red entries in the followed answers list are ones where the _question_ has been deleted. Not the answer. Deleted answers still show up normally (assuming the question is not deleted). (Read: It's possible to unfollow answers on deleted questions, not unfollow deleted answers)

Comment: Ok, it looks like I can remove them now. And on a side note, they also fixed the "A" label on answers on the answers in the list.